# How to translate Linq Expression where clause to hql where clause?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql

For some reason, I need to combine Linq Expression (only where clause) & an HQL where clause into one query.

I find that the `session.Query<T>()` API will translate Linq Expression to a `HqlQuery` object (that extends `HqlExpression`).

How can I translate the Linq Expression where clause to an HQL where clause queryString, and then I can combine another HQL where clause queryString into a new query?

Comment: How are you translating LINQ expressions to an `HqlExpression`? The best I could find was: `ExpressionToSql.Convert<Entity>(e => e.Id > 0)` from FluentNHibernate.

Comment: Thank you. Finally,I implemented it by myself, you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that is not possible to use exists NHibernate API to convert Linq expression to HQL tree.
The HQL tree produced from the Linq expression is not reversable to an actual HQL query.

So I have to translate Linq expression to HQL by self:

```
var expr = GetExpr<Ninja>(x =>
    x.Age > 1 && x.Country.Name == "中国"
    ||
    (x.Id > 10 && x.Country.Name == "中国")
);

var translator = new ExpressionToHqlTranslator("_this");
translator.Translate(expr);
Console.WriteLine(translator.WhereClause);
Console.WriteLine(translator.Patameters);
```

============== result =============

```
WhereClause: (((_this.Age > ?) AND (_this.Country.Name = ?)) OR ((_this.Id > ?) AND (_this.Country.Name = ?)))

Patameters:4
```

=============== the critical  code =============

```
static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetExpr<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr){
    eturn expr;
}


using System;
using System.Linq;
using NHibernate.Linq;
using NHibernate.Linq.Visitors;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using NHibernate;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rhythm.Linq
{
    public class ExpressionToHqlTranslator : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private string _orderBy = "";
        private int? _skip = null;
        private int? _take = null;
        private string _whereClause = "";
        List<object> patameters;

        public int? Skip
        {
            get
            {
                return _skip;
            }
        }

        public int? Take
        {
            get
            {
                return _take;
            }
        }

        public string OrderBy
        {
            get
            {
                return _orderBy;
            }
        }

        public string WhereClause
        {
            get
            {
                return _whereClause;
            }
        }

        public List<object> Patameters
        {
            get
            {
                return patameters;
            }

            set
            {
                patameters = value;
            }
        }

        string prefix;
        public ExpressionToHqlTranslator(string prefix = null)
        {
            this.prefix = string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? null : (prefix + ".");
        }

        public string Translate(Expression expression)
        {
            this.sb = new StringBuilder();
            this.patameters = new List<object>();
            this.Visit(expression);
            _whereClause = this.sb.ToString();
            return _whereClause;
        }

        private static Expression StripQuotes(Expression e)
        {
            while (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
            {
                e = ((UnaryExpression)e).Operand;
            }
            return e;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
        {
            if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && m.Method.Name == "Where")
            {
                this.Visit(m.Arguments[0]);
                LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)StripQuotes(m.Arguments[1]);
                this.Visit(lambda.Body);
                return m;
            }
            else if (m.Method.Name == "Take")
            {
                if (this.ParseTakeExpression(m))
                {
                    Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                    return this.Visit(nextExpression);
                }
            }
            else if (m.Method.Name == "Skip")
            {
                if (this.ParseSkipExpression(m))
                {
                    Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                    return this.Visit(nextExpression);
                }
            }
            else if (m.Method.Name == "OrderBy")
            {
                if (this.ParseOrderByExpression(m, "ASC"))
                {
                    Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                    return this.Visit(nextExpression);
                }
            }
            else if (m.Method.Name == "OrderByDescending")
            {
                if (this.ParseOrderByExpression(m, "DESC"))
                {
                    Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                    return this.Visit(nextExpression);
                }
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The method '{0}' is not supported", m.Method.Name));
        }

        protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression u)
        {
            switch (u.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Not:
                    sb.Append(" NOT ");
                    this.Visit(u.Operand);
                    break;
                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                    this.Visit(u.Operand);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The unary operator '{0}' is not supported", u.NodeType));
            }
            return u;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="b"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
        {
            sb.Append("(");
            this.Visit(b.Left);

            switch (b.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.And:
                    sb.Append(" AND ");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
                    sb.Append(" AND ");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.Or:
                    sb.Append(" OR ");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                    sb.Append(" OR ");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.Equal:
                    if (IsNullConstant(b.Right))
                    {
                        sb.Append(" IS ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(" = ");
                    }
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                    if (IsNullConstant(b.Right))
                    {
                        sb.Append(" IS NOT ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(" <> ");
                    }
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                    sb.Append(" < ");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                    sb.Append(" <= ");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                    sb.Append(" > ");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    sb.Append(" >= ");
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The binary operator '{0}' is not supported", b.NodeType));

            }

            this.Visit(b.Right);
            sb.Append(")");
            return b;
        }


        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
        {
            this.patameters.Add(c.Value);
            sb.Append('?');
            //IQueryable q = c.Value as IQueryable;

            //if (q == null && c.Value == null)
            //{
            //    sb.Append("NULL");
            //}
            //else if (q == null)
            //{
            //    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(c.Value.GetType()))
            //    {
            //        case TypeCode.Boolean:
            //            sb.Append(((bool)c.Value) ? 1 : 0);
            //            break;

            //        case TypeCode.String:
            //            sb.Append("'");
            //            sb.Append(c.Value);
            //            sb.Append("'");
            //            break;

            //        case TypeCode.DateTime:
            //            sb.Append("'");
            //            sb.Append(c.Value);
            //            sb.Append("'");
            //            break;

            //        case TypeCode.Object:
            //            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The constant for '{0}' is not supported", c.Value));

            //        default:
            //            sb.Append(c.Value);
            //            break;
            //    }
            //}

            return c;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression m)
        {
            if (this.prefix != null)
            {
                sb.Append(this.prefix);
            }
            sb.Append(ContactModelPropertyVistHierarchyExpression(m, m.Member.DeclaringType));
            //if (m.Expression != null && m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
            //{
            //    sb.Append(m.Member.Name);
            //    return m;
            //}
            return m;

            //throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The member '{0}' is not supported", m.Member.Name));
        }

        protected bool IsNullConstant(Expression exp)
        {
            return (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant && ((ConstantExpression)exp).Value == null);
        }

        private bool ParseOrderByExpression(MethodCallExpression expression, string order)
        {
            UnaryExpression unary = (UnaryExpression)expression.Arguments[1];
            LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)unary.Operand;

            lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.Evaluator.PartialEval(lambdaExpression);

            MemberExpression body = lambdaExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (body != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_orderBy))
                {
                    _orderBy = string.Format("{0} {1}", body.Member.Name, order);
                }
                else
                {
                    _orderBy = string.Format("{0}, {1} {2}", _orderBy, body.Member.Name, order);
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool ParseTakeExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
        {
            ConstantExpression sizeExpression = (ConstantExpression)expression.Arguments[1];

            int size;
            if (int.TryParse(sizeExpression.Value.ToString(), out size))
            {
                _take = size;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool ParseSkipExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
        {
            ConstantExpression sizeExpression = (ConstantExpression)expression.Arguments[1];

            int size;
            if (int.TryParse(sizeExpression.Value.ToString(), out size))
            {
                _skip = size;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }


    public static string ContactModelPropertyVistHierarchyExpression(Expression expr, Type modelType)
    {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Expression curr = expr;
            // TypedParameterExpression
            while (curr != null)
            {
                if (curr is MemberExpression)
                {
                    var x = curr as MemberExpression;
                    sb.Insert(0, x.Member.Name);
                    curr = x.Expression;
                }
                else if (curr is MethodCallExpression)
                {
                    var x = curr as MethodCallExpression;
                    sb.Insert(0, x.Method.Name);
                    curr = x.Object;
                }
                else if (curr is ParameterExpression)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported Expression type " + curr.GetType().FullName + " for expression " + expr.ToString(), "expr");
                }
                sb.Insert(0, '.');
            }
            return sb.Length > 1 ? sb.Remove(0, 1).ToString() : sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

add dll reference NHibernate.Linq.dll

Comment: What is the Evaluator class?

Comment: NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.Evaluator  from NHibernate.Linq.dll

Comment: NHibernate.Linq.dll was deprecated ages ago.

Comment: Yes,I just use NHibernate.Linq.dll lib as a Linq expression utility, and the Evaluator.PartialEval method's implementiaion is simple, It's not hard to extract the code then remove NHibernate.Linq.dll's reference.